# mysql : group by column (show column with higer value)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have some rows on "MENU" table

```
id, shop, size
1,  1   , 3
2,  1   , 8
3,  2   , 5
```

i need to show 1 row for each **shop** so if **shop id** is same then show the row with high value on column **size**
and results should be like this

```
id, shop, size
2,  1   , 8
3,  2   , 5
```

also if size is 0  on both rows it will display just 1 row

i need something like this

> ```
> SELECT * FROM menu GROUP by shop
> ```

but to show the row with high value

i have tried this but if rows have **0** on **column size** then it shows both of them

```
SELECT a.* FROM menu a                   
LEFT JOIN menu b            
ON a.shop=b.shop AND a.size< b.size
WHERE b.size NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you're using a recent version of MySql that supports *window functions* this is typically resolved with *row_number*:

```
with t as (
  Select *, row_number() over(partition by Shop order by Size desc) rn
  from Menu
)
select Id, Shop, size
from t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The most typical way to solve such tasks is with `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` as shown in Stu's answer.

Another option: Get the maximum size per shop, then use this result to retrieve the rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM menu
WHERE (shop, size) IN
(
  SELECT shop, MAX(size)
  FROM menu
  GROUP by shop
);
```

Another option: select rows for which no row with the same shop but a higher size exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM menu
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT null
  FROM menu better
  WHERE better.shop = menu.shop
  AND better.size > menu.size
);
```

Comment: which one you think is recomanded , which one is fastest way and use less resources?

Comment: All solutions are good. I usually go with the `ROW_NUMBER` / `RANK` / `DENSE_RANK` approach. The idea with this is to read the table only once from disk and then work on with that result. In an ideal world, the optimizer would see that all queries do exactly the same thing and come back with the same execution plan for all of them, but this may be asking a little too much from the DBMS :-)